# How to get data from USDA API into Postgres database plus add one new column

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, api, python-requests

I am using an API to access the USDA food database and pull some nutrient data for a particular food, do some calculations (with another function partially shown here). I would like to find a way to run my function on every food in the database that contains that particular nutrient, "tryptophan", and then add the result to Postgres along with the food name, foodID, and amino acids amounts for each item. Also, if there is a way to narrow it down to standard reference items that would be ideal. Does anyone know how to do this?

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd


apiKey = '' 
foodID = '' 

def nutrient_API(apiKey, foodID):
    #calls get api and json load
    api_resp = json.loads(requests.get('https://api.nal.usda.gov/fdc/v1/' + foodID + '?api_key=' + apiKey).text)
    #only return nutrition information
    api_nutrients = api_resp['foodNutrients']
    #first entry is its description, foodID, and database entry type
    nutrientDict = {"FoodID": [api_resp['description'],foodID, api_resp['dataType']]}

    for items in api_nutrients:
        if 'amount' in items:
            #each entry includes nutrient name, nutrient id, amount, and its respective unit
            nutrientDict.update({(items['nutrient']['name']): [(items['nutrient']['id']),
                (items['amount']),(items['nutrient']['unitName'])]})
        #print(nutrientDict)
    return(nutrientDict)


def trypfunc(foodID):
    dataframe = pd.DataFrame(nutrient_API(apiKey, foodID))
    tryp_g=(dataframe['Tryptophan'][1])
#does some more stuff
    return trypfunc

# I call the above function for one food at a time with the foodID
print("Sesame seeds: ")
trypfunc(foodID='170150')
```

Comment: How about using the API search: https://fdc.nal.usda.gov/api-spec/fdc_api.html#/FDC/getFoodsSearch to just fetch those foods with tryptophan?

Comment: sounds like it could work, I'm just not sure how to set it up

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an API key so I can't verify at this time, still here is how I would start. From here:

https://github.com/USDA/USDA-APIs/issues/64

```
params = {'api_key': key}
data = {'generalSearchInput': 'chia'}
response = requests.post(
    r'https://api.nal.usda.gov/fdc/v1/search',
    params=params,
    json=data
)
```

Then I went here:

https://fdc.nal.usda.gov/fdc-app.html#/?query=Tryptophan

and snooped the request payload:

```
{"includeDataTypes":{"Survey (FNDDS)":true,"Foundation":true,"Branded":true,"SR Legacy":true},"referenceFoodsCheckBox":true,"sortCriteria":{"sortColumn":"description","sortDirection":"asc"},"generalSearchInput":"Tryptophan","pageNumber":1,"exactBrandOwner":null,"currentPage":1}
```

So I figure a minimal example would be:

```
params = {'api_key': key}
data = {'generalSearchInput': 'Tryptophan'}
response = requests.post(
    r'https://api.nal.usda.gov/fdc/v1/search',
    params=params,
    json=data
)
```

[Edited] Got API key. SO when you run the above you get:

```
tryptophan_dict = json.loads(response.text)
tryptophan_dict.keys()                                                                                                                                                     
dict_keys(['foodSearchCriteria', 'totalHits', 'currentPage', 'totalPages', 'foods'])

tryptophan_dict['totalHits']                                                                                                                                               
5124

tryptophan_dict['totalPages']                                                                                                                                              
103
```

You only get one page of results at a page size of 50.  That leaves you with the options of grabbing the totalPages number and iterating over it with responses that have:

```
data = {'generalSearchInput': 'Tryptophan', 'pageNumber': page_number}
```

or just grabbing everything using the totalHits number:

```
data = {'generalSearchInput': 'Tryptophan', 'pageSize': 5124}
```

To get description:

```
for food in tryptophan_dict["foods"]: 
    print(food["description"])
```

Comment: thanks! where do you get the request payload? and from the json data what's the easiest way to just get the 'description' for each?

Comment: thanks for the added info, very helpful. when I try to run it I get an error "AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'text'" - do you do something differently when you ran it?

Comment: oh I think it was because I had put a .text after your previous response string like my previous example.. but now I'm getting another error:     trytophan_dict = json.loads(response.text)
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I'm going to need to see a more complete code snippet. Also was that the complete error message?

Comment: btw, you might want to edit in a few places you spelled tryptophan without the first "p"